# Clone a remote Linux server with rsync and migrate it locally as Virtual Machine

Tags: centos, rsync, migration, clone

I have a CentOS6.9 Linux server remotely on a VPS Provider and I need to clone my remote server on my local computer as a Virtual Machine for examination purposes.

---

I made a full server backup without compression to another remote server (rsync.net) by using the following `rsync` command:

`rsync -auHxv --numeric-ids --delete-after --progress --exclude="/etc/fstab" --exclude="/dev/*" --exclude="/proc/*" --exclude="/sys/*" --exclude="/tmp/*" --exclude="/boot/*" --exclude="/run/*" --exclude="/mnt/*" --exclude="/media/*" --exclude="/backup/*" --exclude="/lost+found" / -e ssh user@server.rsync.net:backup_directory`

---

Would it be possible to use this backup as an image for cloning through Virtual Machine on my local computer, either by using `VMWare Workstation` or `Virtual Box` or any other Virtual Machine Platform ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use DD over SSH and import that as a new VBox image after conversion.  I use GZIP to skip copying gigs of empty space.

```
ssh root@remoteIP  "dd if=/dev/sda | gzip - " | dd of=image.gz
```

Uncompress and convert.

```
gunzip image.gz 
VBoxManage convertdd image image.vdi --format VDI
```

Comment: Thanks. How exclusions are declared ?

Comment: Hey @Cadmos unfortunately DD does not have such a concept. If you wanted to use rsync  *I* would just install the same OS in VBox then run your rsync from there. I think that would be quickest. Although DD would give you a 1:1 copy of the disc.

Comment: I agree it would be better using DD however the free disk space on the VPS that is to be backed up has not enough disk space (almost 20%) and I have to exclude at least /home dir which has the cpanel accounts in.

Comment: my disk is 100GB however now only the 23GB are being used. DD /gzip will create an image of the total capacity of the disk or only for the used space, meaning the 23GB, so the image will be equal/lesser than 23GB ?

Comment: Hey @Cadmos - Using GZIP it should be ~23GB or less, it compresses all the empty space to 0 bytes. Hopefully you should gain some more compression from GZIP as well. When you  GUNZIP it, it will be 100GB though.

Comment: You've right. However I followed all of your steps and after loading the image.VDI in Virtual Box it ends with Fatal: `No bootable medium found!` (Sorry for not voting up your answers, I have not enough score for letting me vote up answers/comments)

Comment: @Cadmos Did you found a solution ? I also want to create a VM from my VPS, but not able to boot on it with this solution. I think my VPS provider have custom /boot images